# Definir valores por default en eje Y amchart

Tags: javascript, css, html5, amcharts

Buen dia, estoy creando una grafica de barras usando la libreria amchart para mostrar datos estadisticos y necesito definir los valores del eje Y para que lleguen hasta 100 y no 80.

por el momento solo llega a 80 y estoy tratando que los valores de la linea vertical lleguen a 100 y no a 80.

este es el codigo que estoy usando, pero no tengo idea de como definir esos valores o si es posible con la libreria(amchart)

```js
function render_grafico(datos, tipo_grafico, escala, eje) {

            am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

            if (tipo_grafico == "barras") {
                var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

                chart.data = datos;
                chart.responsive.enabled = true;
                if (escala == "A")
                    chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#.0";

                var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
                categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "parametro";
                categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

                categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

                var axis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

                axis.title.text = eje == undefined ? "Frecuencia %" : eje;
                axis.title.rotation = -90;
                axis.title.align = "center";
                axis.title.valign = "middle";
                //axis.title.dy = -40;
                axis.title.fontWeight = 600;

                // Create series
                var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
                series.dataFields.valueY = "valor";
                series.dataFields.categoryX = "parametro";

                series.name = "valor";
                series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}" + (escala == undefined || escala == 'P' ? "%" : "") + "[/]";
                series.columns.template.fillOpacity = 1;
                series.columns.template.fill = am4core.color("#00395e"); 
                series.columns.template.width = 100;
                series.stacked = true;


                var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
                columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 1;
                columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;

                var valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
                valueLabel.label.text = "{valueY}" + (escala == undefined || escala == 'P' ? "%" : "");
                valueLabel.label.fontSize = 20;
                valueLabel.label.verticalCenter = "top";
                valueLabel.label.dy = 10;
                valueLabel.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");


            } else {
                var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);
                // Add data
                chart.data = datos;
                chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#.0";
                chart.responsive.enabled = true;

                // Add and configure Series
                var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
                pieSeries.dataFields.value = "valor";
                pieSeries.dataFields.category = "parametro";

                //pieSeries.tooltipText = "{dataFields.category}: {dataFields.value}";
                pieSeries.labels.template.text = "{category}: {value.value}%";
                pieSeries.slices.template.tooltipText = "{category}: [bold]{value.value}%[/]";

                pieSeries.colors.list = [
                    am4core.color("#00395e"),
                    am4core.color("#878786"),
                    am4core.color("#075990"),
                    am4core.color("#338fce"),
                    am4core.color("#b7b7b5"),
                    am4core.color("#656563"),
                    am4core.color("#F7B334")
                ];

            }

            chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
        }
```

y este es el resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero cambiar los valores del lado izquierdo a algo como esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Buen dia, utilice este codigo.

```
            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.position = "left";//Posicion de escala Richard..
            valueAxis.minimum = 10;
            valueAxis.maximum = 100;
            valueAxis.strictMinMax = false; //Cambiar a true para rango no fijos
```